# C- Declaring char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C and am having trouble declaring a character array for a class project.
Here's roughly what I'm doing:

```
char test[]="Test\0";

char *Pointer;
Pointer=test;
```

I then have a function `printString(char* chars)` that takes Pointer as an argument. When I try to compile, I'm told that neither test or Pointer are declared. I'm not sure why, so can someone point me in the right direction.

This is the whole code:

```
main()
{

   char *test2="Test\0";

    printString(test2);
}

printString(char* charArray)
{

    int charPos=0;
    int endOfString=1;

    char al;
    char ah;
    int ax;

    while(endOfString==1)
    {
            al=charArray[charPos];
            ah=0xE;
            ax=ah*256+al;

            interrupt(0x10,ax,0,0,0);


            if(al=='\0')
            {
                    return 0;
            }

            charPos++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: BTW, you don't need to add the null terminator to string literals. That is done for you.

Comment: Try this `Pointer = &test;`. `&` allow you to get the address of a variable.

Comment: @Biduleohm Except it's not needed when it comes to arrays, as arrays naturally decays to pointers.

Comment: `Pointer = test;` is correct, and `Pointer = &test;` is an error. However, your code is fine if it is in `main()`. You can't do `Pointer = test;` outside of a function.

Comment: @McLovin, that's about the whole thing. All my pringString function does is call an interrupt to print each character in the array to the screen. Can anyone at least tell me why I'm being told char test[]="test"; is undeclared?

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Right now it's impossible to answer your question. Also, if you have compiler errors, please include the complete and unedited error log/output in the question.

Comment: Just put up the whole thing, when I compile it, I get the errors--> invalid lvalue" and "test2 is undelcared"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having the NULL character is not necessary there.

Here is why:

When an array of characters is declared and it is initialize, like in your example:

```
char test[] = "Test";
```

The compiler will put the characters from "Test" in the test array, then add a null character so that test can be used as a string like so:

```
    +---+---+---+---+----+
test| T | e | s | t | \0 |
    +---+---+---+---+----+
```

In regards to your question, see if this helps:

```
void print_string( char *p ) {
    while ( *p != '\0' ) {
     printf( "%c", *p );
     p++;
    }

}
```

Remember a C-style string is a sequence of characters and it's always terminated with NULL character.

The function "print_string", for example, expects a pointer to a char as an argument ( you can past the char array you created, and it will work since arrays are treated as pointers. )
The function will print each character until the NULL character is encountered.

IMPORTANT:

```
char test[]  = "Test";
char *test_2 = "Test";
```

In the array version, the characters stored in test can be modified, like elements of any array.
In the pointer version, test points to a string literal, and string literals should NOT be modified.

I believe the problem might be because of that, you are trying to modified a string literal. Doing so causes undefined behavior.

Either use an array or allocate memory and make char pointer point to it.

Comment: Thanks for editing my code Turbo J. I should have copied directly from the test.c file instead of writing it on here.I'm still learning how to write code on here.

Answer (score 0):

For use your function: printString(char* chars).

declare just:

```
char *my_string = "Test";
printString(my_string);
```

Comment: When I do that, I get told "invalid lvalue" and "my_string is undelcared"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is *possibly* because you don't declare the function before you use it. In C you really have to declare everything before it's used. In this case do e.g.

```
void printString(char* charArray);

int main(void)
{
    ...
}

void printString(char* charArray)
{
    ...
}
```